# Correct exception handling with python MySQLdb connection

Tags: python, error-handling, innodb, mysql-python

I created a small/basic python script to insert data into a MySQL database. I included some error handling - mainly to close the connection and/or prevent hanging connections in the case of an error (...but also to ignore some errors).

I thought what I had (see below) was right - it seemed to be working okay. But occasionally I have been getting "Too many connection" errors - which I assumes means I am not actually closing the connection correctly at all (or perhaps error handling isn't right).

```
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host=####, user=####, passwd=####, db=####)
curs=conn.cursor()
try:
    curs.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()           

except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    if e[0]!= ###:
        raise

finally: 
    curs.close()    
    conn.close()
```

(I also tried without `finally:`)

The other (I think important) point is that it is that the MySQL database uses an InnoDB storage engine. This is the first time I have used InnoDB engine and perhaps there are some differences to MyISAM that are relevant here, that I am not aware of (like `conn.commit()`, but for an error).... That seems to be the source of all my other problems!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should remove the `conn.close()` from the `try` body, as it will _always_ be called within the `finally` body. Other than that, it looks like you're releasing your connections properly.

Comment: Thanks Lanzz - sorry I made an error copying the code (was playing around without `finally:`, and had a `conn.close()` in the `try` body **and** the `except` body). 

Have fixed the question (still have the same problem, either way)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue was I wasn't invoking `conn.rollback()` in the `except` clause (and consequently, the connection was not closing properly). One line (see below) *seemed* to fix the issue (I can't be exactly sure if that was this issue - if someone could confirm that would be great).

```
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host=####, user=####, passwd=####, db=####)
curs=conn.cursor()
try:
    curs.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()           

except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    conn.rollback()              #rollback transaction here
    if e[0]!= ###:
        raise

finally: 
    curs.close()    
    conn.close()
```