# Displaying customized exception message based on the error

Tags: python, mysql, database

I want my code to display a custom error message that depends on the type of error it encounters.

```
from .forms import NameForm, IdForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from client_storage import insert
import mysql.connector.errors
from mysql.connector.errors import Error
import MySQLdb


def sign_in(request):
        #we need to handle all the data that was just typed, we'll add a condition for that
        if request.method == "POST":
            #here will construct the form with the POST data
            form = NameForm(request.POST)
            #the next part is to check that the information submitted is valid
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save()
                post.save()
                return HttpResponse(post.question_text)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Form is invalid")
        else:
            form = NameForm()
        return render(request, 'checkin/base.html', {'form': form})

    #this view will be the sign-up view, where new clients will be given new ID numbers for training

def sign_up(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = IdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            post.save()
            ID = post.id_text
            #we'll call an external function that checks membership of the users input in the database
            # query is the first element of the tuple that is returned from insert()
            query = insert(post.id_text)
            if query == 1062:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Already taken ')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('sign_up')
            if query == 1054:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Invalid input')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('sign_up')
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Thank you for signing up!')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('sign_up')

            # if the user enters a number that is already in use raise an 'duplicate' error
            # Capture the exception here
        else:
            return HttpResponse('That text is invalid')
    else:
        form = IdForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/base.html', {'form': form})

For the `except` block I'm trying to figure out how to display either "Already taken" or "Invalid input" depending on the error code. However only "Already taken" ever appears. I feel like the problem is that the exception is being thrown before it even gets to the `if` clauses?
```

I'm using another file for the `INSERT` process:

```
import MySQLdb
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from django.contrib import messages

#Use a function to insert new information into the database

def insert(info):
    #open a connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','password', 'CLIENTS')
    #prepare a cursor
    cursor = db.cursor()
    #prepare SQL query
    sql = "INSERT INTO clients(ID) VALUES (%s)" % info

    try:
        #execute the command
        cursor.execute(sql)
        #commit changes to the database
        print 'success'
        db.commit()
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        #return the first element in the tuple that contains the error message, which will be the errorcode
         if e[0] == 1062:
            return e[0]
         if e[0] == 1054:
            return e[0]

    #disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

**EDIT** The problem seems to have been that I was using `mysql.connector.error` instead of `MySQLdb.Error`.The `mysql` website seems to only use the former. And there isn't a lot of official documentation on the latter it seems, but thankfully I found [this site.](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/5535/MySQLdb.Error) I changed the code so the `sign_in` view would recieve the `returned` info from the external `insert` fuction then act accordingly.

Comment: On [this page of the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html), the third example down shows how to use a conditional for the error number of the exception.  In your attempt, you never *capture* the error (or it never gets assigned to anything) so you can't compare to anything. ```bool(Error(errno=1062))``` probably evaluates to ```True``` so it always *works*.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions,

Comment: The comments of @wwii are correct. You may edit your `try .. except` block and catch the right exceptions then return your desired string/type output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what @wwii said in the comments, you need to edit your `try ... except` block in order to catch the exception. See this page of [documentations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html).

Also, in your actual code `Error(errno=1062)` return always a non nil string which validate your `if` statement. And this is why you got always the `Already Taken` message.

In order to handle this issue, you should modify your code into something like this example:

```
# What you need to import
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    insert(post.id_text)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Thank you for signing up ')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('sign_in')

# Catch the error exception
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    # Error code 1062: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_DUP_ENTRY:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Already taken") 
        return HttpResponseRedirect('sign_up')

    # Error code 1054: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_bad_field_error
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Invalid input")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('sign_up')
```

**Edit:**

**Your edited answer is correct within both `Python2` and `Python3`.**

Otherwise, if you're using `Python2` you can do something like this.

```
try:
    #execute the command
    cursor.execute(sql)
    #commit changes to the database
    print 'success'
    db.commit()
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
     if e.args[0] == 1062 or e.args[0] == 1054:
        # e.args[0] is the error code in int format
        # e.args[1] is the complete error message in str format
        return e.args[1]
     else:
        # I didn't test all the cases, but this message
        # can save you more time during the debug later
        # if your code catch another error code rather than 1062 or 1054
        return "Something odd happened"
```

Also you can do something like this (This example if valid for both `Python2` and `Python3`):

```
try:
    #execute the command
    cursor.execute(sql)
    #commit changes to the database
    print 'success'
    db.commit()
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
     if e[0] == 1062 or e[0] == 1054:
        # e[0] is the error code in int format
        # e[1] is the complete error message in str format
        return e[1]
     else:
        # Good for the debug
        return "Something odd happened"
```

Comment: I still seem to be having an issue with outputting the customized text, I'm getting the proper error code, however it's not within the website like I want. It's just displaying the Django error page

Comment: You mean in the second file where you use `except mysql.connector.Error as e: ...   return e ` ?

Comment: Your question confuses me. In the first block of `try ... except` you'll catch the exception then add a message then return a `HttpResponseRedirect` so in the front end, after going throgh the exception, the page will redirect to your signup page. In the second block of `try ... except` you'll catch any exception of the type `mysql.connector.Error` then return the error. Maybe you should try to catch the exception code in the second block then create a custom message there. Try it then leave your feedbacks.

Comment: Yea I realized that I was catch exceptions in two different places, I actually deleted all the `try ... except` code from my second file and it didn't effect the output at all. It's almost 2:30am (hate when this happens so late lol) where I live so I'll try it tomorrow then report back

Comment: So you need to debug carefuly your code. if not you can edit your question and i'll try to help you as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm still stuck, my current code is the closest I have to a solution. Every other method doesn't seem to actually capture the `exception`

Comment: Okay, edit your question and try to put the max possible of information. I'll try to help you.

Comment: That's all the relevant info I can give you. However I realized I'm using two libraries: `mysql.connector` and `MySQLdb`, both of them have their own classes for handling `exceptions`. Right now I'm just focusing on the second file and trying to get it to actually `print` the message I want depending on the error code. Then I'll be able to do the rest, do you think that makes sense? Thanks again, I'll edit the second file

Comment: Okay so replacing `mysql.connector` with `MySQLdb` seems to have done the trick, it's actually `print`ing the string. I'm gonna head to bed now, I need to, I'll figure out what else I need to replace. I don't think `MySQLdb` has the attribute `errno`

Comment: So with `MySQLdb` you get the complete string ? The examples in the documentations used to use `mysql.connector` to catch only the errors codes then raise an exception. At least that's what the documentation said. Or maybe you can, also, use `mysql.connector` and use a costum error strings. I think it's not a good idea to print the standard error string in front of the user. This will guide, maybe, to SQLinjenction if there is any SQLi point injection.

Comment: Yea it gives me the string, and I don't intend on printing the standard error string. I just wanted the program to actually behave how I wanted. I know it uses `mysql.connector` but `MySQLdb` also has it's own set of `error` classes. Here's another Stack question using `MySQLdb` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721109/correct-exception-handling-with-python-mysqldb-connection

Comment: Here's a bunch of examples using it: http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/5535/MySQLdb.Error

Comment: Good. But you can still create your custom exception using the error code. Otherwise, you have the choice. Good luck.

Comment: Oh I'll still be using error codes, right now if I want to I can return the error message as a tuple: `(1062, "Duplicate entry '2501' for key 'PRIMARY'")`, from there I can just select the first element, which is `1062` in this case. There's also `MySQLdb.constants.ER_DUP_ENTRY`, when I finish it I'll update the post and let you know

Comment: I figured it out and edited it, let me know what you think. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130161/discussion-between-nexus66-and-amon).